# How do i express a in terms of the other vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I've been having issues solving this math problem. I just can't seem to understand how to incorporate the two c vectors. I've tried 2c - b and -b + c +c (both equivalent) and I've gotten it incorrect. Is there someone who can possibly lead me to the right path? Thanks!

[Triangle made up of vectors a, b, and c](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUf73.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe from the picture that:

$$2\vec{c} + \vec{a} = \vec{b}$$

Now solve for $\vec{a}$:

$$\vec{a} = \vec{b} - 2\vec{c}$$

Comment: I cannot believe I didn't look at it that way. Thank you so much! I'll use the same technique next time when I'm stuck :D